# In Magento 1.9, based on a condition, change checkout/onepage layout

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout

I want to change a `checkout/onepage` layout based on a condition.

**Example:**

```
<?php
    $coupon = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getCouponCode();
    if(($coupon == "SE50") || ($coupon == "SE00")){
    }
?>
```

To show`checkout.xml`

```
<action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-right.phtml</template></action>
```

I mean this page:

[image]

```
if(empty($coupon))

<action method="setTemplate"><template>page/checkout-onepage.phtml</template></action>
```

A page like:

[image]

Note: `checkout-onepage.phtml` is a custom page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a helper function to set the template based on a condition. Follow the below code.

Change the action tag in your `layout.xml` to the below.

```
 <action method="setTemplate"><template helper="your_module/getLayout" /></action>
```

In your module's helper file `Data.php` add the below code.

```
public function getLayout()
{
    $coupon = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getCouponCode();
    if(($coupon == "SE50") || ($coupon == "SE00")){

        return 'page/2columns-right.phtml';
    }
    else
    {
        return 'page/checkout-onepage.phtml';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for code Bro you mean create Data.php file in `app\code\core\Mage\Checkout\Helper`

Comment: No don't modify core files, add it to your existing custom module's Helper/Data.php or create a new custom module

Comment: Same idea here ... +1

Comment: @Piyush: Bro showing `Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Your_Module_Helper_Data' not found in D:\xampp\htdocs\ramesh\sliver-exchange\app\Mage.php on line 547`

Comment: I have already create module called `SilverExchange`

Comment: please replace `your_module`  in layout file with your module name

Comment: I have paste your code in `app\code\local\SilverExchange\Declaration\Helper\Data.php` And `<action method="setTemplate"><template helper="declaration/getLayout" /></action>` paste in `app\design\frontend\base\default\layout\checkout.xml` inside `<checkout_onepage_index translate="label">`

Comment: @Piyush: Yes bro i have replace see `<action method="setTemplate"><template helper="declaration/getLayout" /></action>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66821/discussion-between-ramesh-s-and-piyush).

Comment: @Piyush My question diff form this post, How can i set condition like selected zip code ares free shipping, currently i am using Webshop matrix as a shipping method option, free shipping working, how can i implement my specific condition like selected zipcode free shipping, in shopping cart pricing rule not working, so how can i write condition in checkout page.

Comment: Post :: https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/224918/39050

Answer (score 3):

Either change your `checkout.xml` (or better add this to your `local.xml`)

```
...
<action method="setTemplate">
    <template helper="module/helper/yourMethod" />
</action>
...
```

Add a custom module with a helper method like ...

```
public function yourMethod()
{
    $coupon = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getCouponCode();
    if ($coupon == 'SE50' || $coupon == 'SE00') {
        return 'page/2columns-right.phtml';
    } else {
        return 'page/2columns-left.phtml';
    }
}
```

Comment: I will try both functions

Comment: Its the same as  Piyush posted ... he was just faster :)

Comment: Ha ha right... :)