# Change media template for single product

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, template, xml

I am trying to update the media template via XML in Magento. Somehow my method is not working:

First I included `<?php var_dump($this->getNameInLayout()); ?>`in the template to get the correct block name. In this case the output is: "product.info.media"

Second step is to updated the product design via manage products > Product > Design > Custom Layout Update. Here I try to update the xml for this single product:

```
<reference name="product.info.media">
    <action method="setTemplate"><name>ecommerceteam/cloud-zoom/catalog/product/view/media-venst.phtml</name></action>
</reference>
```

This is not working.

Update: 
This is what happens in the catalog.xml

```
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info" template="catalog/product/view.phtml">
            <block type="catalog/product_view_media" name="product.info.media" as="media" template="catalog/product/view/media.phtml"/>
```

Update:

I was not able to update a child block via the product xml layout. I resorted to switching the theme.

Comment: The second step works only for simple products, may be a bug.

Comment: you can try using helper function, like I did in this answer - https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/196465/20064

Comment: This is a simple product. Somehow using reference name="product.info" does work.

Comment: though its working, check once in your theme's `catalog.xml` for block `product.info` , if it has child blocks they will be replaced too

Comment: I added a part off the catalog.xml to the original question. I looks like product.info.media is a child block off product.info.

Comment: yes it is child block , So you should only override the media block

Comment: Does this affect the XML is should use?

Comment: Use the xml file for this, you can add this in local.xml also

Answer (score 0):

You can update for example with this:

```
<reference name="content">
<block type="cms/block" name="your_name">
    <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>your_blockid</block_id></action>
</block>
</reference>
```

If you want to put a block in your template. Or you can update with a .phtml from for example from your template folder:

```
<reference name="content">
<block type="core/template" name="your_name" as="your_page"  template="page/html/your.phtml" >
</block>
</reference>
```