# magento : Give condition in xml file

Tags: magento-1.9, xml

Condition in xml file **catalog.xml**

```
 <xsl:if product="bundle" >
   <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.clone_prices" as="prices" template="catalog/product/view/price_clone.phtml"/> 
 </xsl:if>
```

Doesn't come with the prices in bundled product. Please suggest if the systax is right or other alternative suggestion

Comment: <xsl:if product="bundle" >
       <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.clone_prices" as="prices" template="catalog/product/view/price_clone.phtml"/> 
      </xsl:if>

Comment: No, wrong syntax. Maybe this is helperfull ... https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/196461/in-magento-1-9-based-on-a-condition-change-checkout-onepage-layout

Comment: Thank you for your reply but that is not to do with xml change at the end ! IF there is any other solution would also be appreciated !!